# After using sudo stll Permission denied

Tags: mysql, macos, permissions, sudo

I run Mac OS 10.9.5 and I am wanting to change my mySQLWorkbench root password and followed these [instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) with this command (obviously inputing the correct directory and all)

> sudo kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`

I get this error

> cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid: Permission denied
>   Password:
>   usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
>          kill -l [exit_status]
>          kill -signal_name pid ...
>          kill -signal_number pid ...

Although I am  on an admin account on my Mac ( the usage: part comes after putting the password ) 
I tried using with sudo !! but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from: [Terminal doesnt not recognise mysqld and mysql commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159750/terminal-doesnt-not-recognise-mysqld-and-mysql-commands/40160227)

The cat command surrounded by backticks is executed by the shell before running the sudo command (If the file was readable for everyone the shell will execute something like: sudo kill 12345).

To run the cat as root you should run this command:

sudo bash -c 'kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid`'

That way, you run bash as root, which in turn runs the kill command, and thus reads the rodongi.pid file as root.