# Terminal doesnt not recognise mysqld and mysql commands

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, sudo

I am runnin OSX 10.9.5 and while trying to reset my MySQL root pasword I typed this:

> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

After being asked  for the admin password, I got this error :

> sudo: mysqld_safe: command not found

I wrote this in

> cd /usr/local/mysql

Also, I have a problem with the sudo command, event though I am logged on the admin account my account, It gives me often permission denied, like using this command for basically the same problem ( reseting my root password )

> sudo kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid`

I then got

> cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid: Permission denied
>
> Password:

After entering the password …

> usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
>          kill -l [exit_status]
>          kill -signal_name pid ...
>          kill -signal_number pid ...

I have no idea why

- 1) I dont have the permission even though I used the sudo command( and another time sudo!! )
- 2) Why msql-bash doesn't not recognise the mysql and mysqld command ( I also tried in terminal-bash;does not work either)

Comment: Use `which mysql` to check if you have installed MySQL on your Mac.

Comment: I do have mysql installed. I even can launch a mysql server but cant access MySQLWorkbench, because I need the orrt passowrd. Anyway I tried it in terminal-bash and in mysql-bash, and got no response. rodongi$ which mysql
rodongi$

Comment: If in terminal bash `which mysql` doesn't return any result how do you know you have mysql installed?

Comment: I got MySQL in System Preferences :)

Comment: `type -a mysql` should show where it is installed. What does it return?

Comment: type -a mysql
-bash: type: mysql: not found

Comment: are you using MAMP or any similar bundle for MySQL in MacOSx?

Comment: I dont believe so, I just installed MySQL and MySQLWorkbench , I just want to create my own blog :) And I am quite new to mysql and the command line

Comment: ok, last try. In Terminal bash execute `ps aux | grep mysqld`. If you don't receive at least 2 results different to the command executed then I am pretty sure you only have installed MySQL Workbench but not the MySQL server.

Comment: I did get 2 results:

Comment: `rodongi          4660   0,4  0,0  2423368    172 s000  U+    7:58     0:00.00 grep mysqld
_mysql           4088   0,0  1,6  2852636  68932   ??  Ss    7:33     0:00.62 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid`

Comment: Actually, while we were troubleshooting I turned on the my MySQL server on, and thats why there are 2 results, I tried it with the MySQL server off and indeed I got 1 only result

Comment: then now you could be able to use the mysql commands if you create an alias in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` with: `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH`

Comment: If installing mysql client tools and or finding them in your operating system is difficult for you, and you are trying to create an online blog, I would suggest not futzing with a local osx box and just use some online blogger

Comment: @Dez I did it and tried kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid` and got -bash: cat: command not found, and mysql -v, which didnt work earlier , I got ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Dew , yeah it could be another simple option but im going for the customized blog, the one I can make myself, instead of using pre made blog themes. :)

Comment: @Falanpin you haven't installed `cat`. Use `macports` or `brew` (Homebrew), whichever package manager you prefer. But as @Drew said, it seems you are getting in a "darker place" you now have the ability to manage. Anyway you can only to learn trying.

Comment: @Dez I will try however :) I in fact used homebrew to install rails, should I run brew install … ? Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

#### First problem

You're trying to execute the command `mysqld_safe`, so that command should be on the *PATH* where the terminal looks for commands. (You can view these locations by running `echo $PATH`. The different locations are separated with a colon).

Since you're trying to run a file that is in the local directory you should type `./mysqld_safe` to tell the shell that you're giving a path to file, otherwise it'll search for it in the *PATH*. (You can run the file from anywhere by specifying the full path).

Another solution is to make a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/` that points to /usr/local/mysql/mysqld_safe` (which is the path to the command if I understood you correctly). That way you can run the command from anywhere because it's in the path the shell is looking for.

#### Second Problem

The `cat` command surrounded by backticks is executed by the shell *before* running the sudo command (If the file was readable for everyone the shell will execute something like: `sudo kill 12345`).

To run the `cat` as root you should run this command:

```
sudo bash -c 'kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid`'
```

That way, you run bash as root, which in turn runs the `kill` command, and thus reads the `rodongi.pid` file as root.

Comment: Alright, I got the path to mysqld_safe with echo $PATH. Then what must I do ?

Comment: I tried with sudo bash -c 'kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid`' . But I get  cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/rodongi.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Comment: @Falanpin I'm not sure what you mean by "I got the path to mysqld_safe with echo $PATH". echo $PATH shows the locations where the shell searches for commands you type. If you specify the full location of the file, then the PATH isn't in the game, and the terminal will just run the file you told it to.

Comment: I don't know mysql, so I can't help you much with your second comment. I copied the path to `cat` from your question, so I don't know why it doesn't exist. Maybe MySql isn't running?

Comment: @Idjol I am so sorry, I am quite new to this so please forgive my lack of knowledge :) I wrote `echo $PATH /usr/local/mysql/ ` And got ` /Users/rodongi/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin /usr/local/mysql`. I am not sure what to do now with this

Comment: I'll try to explain again: when you write commands (like `cat`, `sudo`, etc.) in the terminal, it expects to find equivalently named (executable) files in certain locations. These locations are stored in the environment variable "PATH" which you can see the value of with `echo $PATH` (`$` replaces the variable with its value). In addition to writing the name of the commands (like `cat`), you can write the full location of executable files to run them (for example, `/bin/cat`). What I suggested is instead of writing `mysqld_safe`, you should type `/usr/loca/mysql/mysqld_safe`

Comment: The `echo` command just prints its arguments (whatever follows the word "echo"), so running `echo $PATH /usr/local/mysql/` prints the PATH value and then "/usr/local/mysql/". This is the reason you got the mentioned result.